# Facebook Logout issue

Tags: facebook

I'm using the following code to logout from Facebook.

```
string url = string.Format("https://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next={0}&access_token={1}", 
                           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebooklogout"], 
                           token)
```

Note :

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebooklogout"]="http://localhost:56481/MenUs.Web/REGISTRATION/userinterestgroups.aspx"
```

But instead of logging out, it's directing me to my Facebook profile page.

Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the above issue long ago by using the following javascript on click of "Save Button".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function logoutFacebook() {

        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var ID = document.getElementById('hfID').value
            FB.init({ apiKey: ID });
            FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);
        }
        function handleSessionResponse(response) {
            FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is [m.facebook.com](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17217) bug that says next is being ignored. You could always use `https://www.facebook.com/logout` instead.

Also your logout URL has to be in the domain of the app you registered on Facebook, localhost will not work.

```
string url = string.Format("https://www.facebook.com/logout?confirm=1&next={0}&access_token={1}", 
                       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Facebooklogout"], 
                       token)
```

Please take note above, the logout URL *must* be in the same domain as the app.  So the above would not redirect to localhost:xxx

Comment: Code is above, not sure what else you need.